# knockout.js calling click even when jquery template is rendered

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Why would the click even get fired for showFlawDetails when the template renders?

```
app.viewModel.caseStudy.showFlawDetails = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        app.viewModel.caseStudy.selectedFlaw(index);
    };

<script id="flawTemplate" type="text/html">
    {{each(index, value) $data}}
    <div class="flaw">
    <div class="Title" data-bind="click: app.viewModel.caseStudy.showFlawDetails(index)"> Flaw: ${value.Title} </div>
    <div class="Items" data-bind="visible: app.viewModel.caseStudy.selectedFlaw() == index">
     <div>Title: <input type="text" data-bind="value: value.Title" /></div>
     <div>Check: <input type="text" data-bind="value: value.Check" /></div>
    {{each(index1, value1) value.Details}}
         <div>${value1.Key}: <input type="text" data-bind="value: value1.Value" /></div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click (and event) bindings expect that you pass it a reference to a function and not the actual evaluation of it.

So, in your case it is trying to set the click event equal to the **result** of `app.viewModel.caseStudy.ShowFlawDetails(index)`.

To make this work you would either need to wrap it in an anonymous function like:

`click: "function() { app.viewModel.caseStudy.showFlawDetails(index); }"`

or if you don't like the anonymous function, then you would need to find a way to move the function to the caseStudy object and put an index on your caseStudy object, so you can access it directly.  If it helps look at the Avoiding anonymous functions in event bindings in [this post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html) of mine.

Also, here is a sample of maintaining an index property on an object by subscribing to changes to its parent observableArray: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CXBFN/

Comment: That sorting is pretty sweet.  My next task was going to do something like that.  You are def the face of Knockout.js.

Comment: This is another question, but can you add a remove task to that sample?

Comment: There are several ways to do it.  Here is a sample where the parent is passed into the constructor and used in a `removeMe` function. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xJNqg/